# Automatic complete boundedness for bilinear and multilinear maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

$\newcommand{\cb}{\mathrm{cb}}$Let $T : X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear map between Banach spaces. We have the following results concerning automatic complete boundedness:

1. $\|T : X \rightarrow \min(Y)\|_{\cb} = \|T\|$, no matter the operator space structure on $X$.
2. In particular, $\|T : \min(X) \rightarrow \min(Y)\|_{\cb} = \|T\|$.
3. $\|T : \max(X) \rightarrow Y\|_{\cb} = \|T\|$, no matter the operator space structure on $Y$.
4. In particular, $\|T : \max(X) \rightarrow \max(Y)\|_{\cb} = \|T\|$.

Let $T : X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n \rightarrow Y$ be a multilinear map between Banach spaces. Let us consider the notion of complete boundedness associated to the Haagerup tensor product (in the book *Operator Spaces*, by Effros and Ruan, this notion is called multiplicative boundedness).

I am curious about whether we have versions of 1, 2, 3, and 4 in that situation. I already know we cannot have 1: consider the map $T : \ell_2 \times \ell_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $T(x, y) = \langle x, \overline{y}\rangle$. Then the corresponding linear map $\tilde{T} : C \otimes_h R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ cannot be completely bounded, since $C \otimes_h R = S_{\infty}$.

What about 2, 3, and 4? Is there anything special about the case $n = 2$?

Thank you!